# Comparing two created objects in Python

Tags: python

I have a class `DooDadX` that is inheriting from another class `DooDad`. I'm trying to look at the left hand side, `self`, and if it is a `DooDadX` instance it will be a different color.

The main problem I am having is I need to find out if `self`, in `__mod__`, is a `DooDadX` instance or not. If it is, the color will be green, if it's not, the color will be from my inherited class.

In my test code I have `DooDadX` being called on the left side. This should change the color to green but I am getting the color blue.

I could link all of my code but it's about 114 lines with the test code. If this isn't sufficient please let me know.

```
class DooDadX(DooDad):
    def __init__(self, color, weight, value):
        super().__init__(color, weight, value)
        self._serial = "-" + str(self._serial)
        self._name = " DooDadX "


    def __mod__(self, other):
        if self == DooDadX:
            self._color = "green"
        maxWeight = max(self._weight, other._weight)
        rightValue = other._weight
        newDooDadX = DooDadX(self._color, maxWeight, rightValue)
        return newDooDadX
```

This is my test code.

```
    if __name__=="__main__":
        doodads = []
        doodads.append(DooDad("red", 5, 10))
        doodads.append(DooDad("red", 8, 9,))
        doodads.append(DooDad("blue", 20, 15))
        doodads.append(DooDad("green", 2, 5))
        doodads.append(DooDadX("blue", 10, 12))
        doodads.append(doodads[0] + doodads[1])
        doodads.append(doodads[2] + doodads[0])
        doodads.append(doodads[3] - doodads[1])
        doodads.append(doodads[1] - doodads[3])
        doodads.append(doodads[0] * doodads[1])
        doodads.append(doodads[0] * doodads[2])
        doodads.append(doodads[0] / doodads[3])
        doodads.append(doodads[2] % doodads[4])
        doodads.append(doodads[4] % doodads[2])

        for doodad in doodads:
            print(doodad)
```

Comment: use `isinstance(self, derived)`

Comment: Could you explain what the code is supposed to do? It seems to mutate `self` *and* create a new `DooDadX`. Why is this the behaviour for `%`? If you want to know if `self` is a `DooDadX` instance but *not* an instance of a type derived from `DooDadX`, you could do `if self.__class__.__name__ == 'DooDadX'`, but that doesn't feel very Pythonic.

Comment: In my test code I have a list of objects made. This is the one that is giving me problems. The left side is a DooDadX (in my list [4] is DooDadX) I should be getting green, but I am getting blue for the color.
 
        doodads.append(DooDadX("blue", 10, 12)
 
 
        doodads.append(doodads[4] % doodads[2])

Comment: Why not just store the color on the class?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - the test code really hasn't helped anything. *What's the point of this code?*

Comment: I put my test code on it. The color in the class is based on which object is on the left hand side in the test code. It is an assignment, no particular reason for the code. Everything else works but this last part involving the inheritance of the super class.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if self == DooDadX:
```

by this:

```
if isinstance(self, DooDadX):
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if self is an instance of `DooDadX` or if it is an instance of any inherited class of `DooDadX`, do as @Joe recommended. If you want to test if self is ONLY an instance of `DooDadX` use [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) as such:

```
if type(self) == DooDadX
```

Hope that this slight distinction is helpful.